# max-width is not working well with percentage

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with "max-width" property in css.
in my website, there is a title which is limited to only one line and have this property when overflowing:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

everything works fine and the overflow behaves well, but for some reason, when I use percentage in max-width property, it doesn't shrink the title's div.

**CSS**:

```
.card-content-title {

  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;

  max-width: 80%;

  text-align: left;
  font-family: $roboto-condensed-regular;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: $inactive-text-color;

  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card-menu">
        <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
        <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
        <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
        <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="card-content-title">(here is the title)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result**:

[image: with overflow issue]

and if I change the max-width to pixels, instead of percentages:

```
max-width: 200px
```

**Result**:

[image: without the overflow issue]

**is there any way to avoid the overflowing behavior when I use percentages?**

EDIT: 
there is the css of .row:

```
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you inspect the `row` which is the parent of `card-content-title` and find out the width of it?

Comment: Does the parent element have a set width?

Comment: for fun, what happens if you stick a .card-content .row { box-sizing: border-box; } in the mix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below snippet, and it has two sections one with `50% max-width` and another with `200px max-width`.

Note: In the code you copied here, there is closing `div` missing.

```css
.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 400px;
}

.card-content-title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;

  text-align: left;
  font-family: $roboto-condensed-regular;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: $inactive-text-color;

  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.card-content-title-1 {
  max-width: 50%;
}
.card-content-title-2 {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card-menu">
    <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
    <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
    <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
    <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-content-title card-content-title-1">
        (here is the title here is the title here is the title here is the title)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="card-menu">
    <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
    <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
    <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
    <div class=" card-menu-item"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-content-title card-content-title-2">
        (here is the title here is the title here is the title here is the title)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```